# Can I use a painless script on a GET to update a counter?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I have an index with documents that have an "access count" field which is intended to store the number of times that the document has been accessed.  (Much like this web page.)

Of course I can use an update after each get to update the field, but is there a way to attach a Painless script to the get request to increment the field?  Something like:

```
doc['access_count'] += 1;
```

I don't see an obvious answer out of the documentation, but if anyone has done this it would be helpful to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GET call is supposed to be [idempotent](https://restfulapi.net/idempotent-rest-apis/), i.e. calling the same URI multiple times doesn't change the underlying resource. So what you're asking goes against that principle and that's (luckily) not possible to do it.

You'll need to update a counter on that document separately.